# Kendo AutoComplete - force users to make valid selection

Tags: kendo-ui

I've got a few Kendo AutoComplete fields linked to remote data (hundreds of possibilities, so DropDownList is not an option).

How can I force users to make a selection from the displayed list?

I'm also retrieving the additional data that's returned from the data source, e.g.

```
$("#station").kendoAutoComplete({
    dataSource: stationData,
    minLength: 2,
    dataTextField: 'name',
    select: function(e){
        var dataItem = this.dataItem(e.item.index());
        console.dir(dataItem);
    }
});
```

I'm doing additional stuff with the data in `dataItem` and it needs to be a valid selection.

Thanks

SOLVED:
I think I was possibly over-complicating things. The answer is pretty simple and is posted below.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
var valid;
$("#staton").kendoAutoComplete({
  minLength: 2,
  dataTextField: "name",
  open: function(e) {
    valid = false;
  },
  select: function(e){
    valid = true;
  },
  close: function(e){
    // if no valid selection - clear input
    if (!valid) this.value('');
  },
  dataSource: datasource
});
```

Comment: Using this method, if a user doesn't make a valid selection, whatever they have typed into the AutoComplete is cleared `onblur` which is the result I'm after

Comment: In my tests the "close" event is not fired if the user typed a value that returned 0 elements from the server. That is, I start typing "1234.." which fetches nothing from the server and then exit the text field, the "close" event is not fired :-(

Comment: This is not the right answer. You should use the "change" event, not "close".

Answer (score 8):

This method allows users to type whatever they like into the AutoComplete if list not opens. There are two corrections to fix this:

1. initialize variable valid as false:

   var valid = false;
2. Check if no valid selection in change event, but not in close:

   ```
   ...
   change: function(e){ if (!valid) this.value(''); }
   ```

Comment: Agree with @Jakobovski, this is much better. If a user mistypes something and the list closes, Mat's solution will trigger the close event and clear the field right away. This modification clears the input only on the real blur event and lets the user search through the list.

Comment: As I said above the "close" event is not fired when the user types a value that returns no "hits" from the server. So this is a better solution. Dror

Answer (score 4):

The answer the OP posted, in addition to the answer suggested by @Rock'n'muse are definitely good propositions, but both miss an important and desired functional aspect.

When utilizing the solution given by @Mat and implementing the `change`-vice-`close` suggestion from @Rock'n'muse, the typed-in value indeed clears from the widget if no selection is made from the filtered data source.  This is great; however, if the user types in something valid and selects a value from the filtered list, *then* places the cursor at the end of the value and types something which now *invalidates* the value (doesn't return any valid selections from the data source), the typed-in value is not cleared from the widget.

What's happening is that the `isValid` value remains `true` if the previously typed-in (and valid) value should be altered.  The solution to this is to set `isValid` to `false` as soon as the filtering event is triggered.  When the user changes the typed-in value, the widget attempts to filter the data source in search of the typed-in value.  Setting `isValid` to `false` as soon as the `filter` event is triggered ensures a "clean slate" for the `change` event as suggested by the solution from @Rock'n'muse.

Because we're setting `isValid` to false as soon as the `filtering` event is triggered, we do not need to do so in the `open` event (as data source filtering must occur before the user will ever see an option to select).  Because of this, the `open` event binding was removed from @Mat's solution.  This also means the initial assignment of `false` upon declaration of `isValid` is superfluous, but variable assignment upon declaration is always a good idea.

Below is the solution from @Mat along with the suggestions from @Rock'n'muse and with the `filtering` implementation applied:

```js
var isValid = false;
$("#staton").kendoAutoComplete({
    minLength: 2,
    dataTextField: "name",
    select: function () {
        valid = true;
    },
    change: function (e) {
        // if no valid selection - clear input
        if (!valid) {
            e.sender.value("");
        }
    },
    filtering: function () {
        valid = false;
    },
    dataSource: datasource
});
```

As an addendum, using the `select` event binding to set and evaluate a simple boolean value as @Mat proposes is *much* cleaner, simpler and faster than using a jQuery `$.each(...)` on the data source in order to make sure the typed-in value matches an actual item of the data source within the `change` event.  This was my first thought at working a solution before I found the solution from @Mat (this page) and such is my reasoning for up-voting his solution and his question.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps, can you make your own validation by using the `blur` event :

```
$("#station").blur(function() {
    var data = stationData,
        nbData = data.length,
        found = false;

    for(var iData = 0; iData < nbData; iData++) {
         if(this.value === data[iData].yourfieldname) // replace "yourfieldname" by the corresponding one if needed
             found = true;
    }
    console.log(found);
});
```

You can check [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/scaillerie/TuJwU/).

Comment: Thanks Samuel, I think I can probebly work with something like that. It does have a problem though, in that `found` returns `false` on select before it returns `true` on blur (not sure why).

Comment: I don't understand 'found' is the variable that I have set and only exists in the scope of the blur event... Perhaps have you added a test with the same varable on the select event? if this is the case, it is normal: select occurs before the field is autocompleted...

Comment: Hi. I haven't implemented anything yet -- this is just a comment on your fiddle. In Chrome's console, false is returned as soon as a selection is made. True is then returned when you click out of the input field.

Answer (score 0):

You most likely need some custom logic which to intercept each key stroke after the min length of two symbols is surpassed, and prevent the option to enter a character which makes the user string not match *any* of the items from the autocomplete list.

For this purpose intercept the change event of the Kendo autocomplete and compare the current input value from the user against the items from the filtered list.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps,

```
$("#autocomplete_id").val("");

$("#autocomplete").kendoAutoComplete({
    dataSource: datasource,
    minLength: 1,
    dataTextField: "catname",
    dataValueField:"id",
    select: function(e) {                
        var dataItem = this.dataItem(e.item.index());                
        $("#autocomplete_id").val(dataItem.id);
    },
    dataBound: function(e){
        $("#autocomplete_id").val("");
    }
});
```

FYI, autocomplete_id is a hidden field to store the value of the autocomplete. - Sometimes, we would like to have the dataValueField other than dataTextField. So, it serves its purpose.

In this you can get the value of the autocomplete "id" from the element autocomplete_id - which is dataValueField from serverside.

In databound, its values is set to null, and on select, it is assigned the "id" value.

Comment: That doesn't really answer the question -- it still allows users to type whatever they like into the AutoComplete and doesn't force them to choose a valid option.

Answer (score 0):

Although the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13614495/5004479) works, it is not the best solution.

The solution provided doesn't take into account if the user enters a value before even the kendo AutoComplete widget triggers the open event. In result, the value entered is not forced and therefore, the entry/selection is invalid.

My approach assumes that the application is running in **MVC** and the array is passed in **ViewData**. But this can be changed to suit your environment.

**My approach:**

```
var validSelect, isSelected;
$("#staton").kendoAutoComplete({
    minLength: 2,
    filter: "startswith",
    dataTextField: "name",
    filtering: function(e) {
        validSelect = false;
        dataArr = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewData["allStatons"]));
        // for loop within the ViewData array to find for matching ID
        for (var i = 0; i < dataArr .length; i++){
            if (dataArr[i].ID.toString().match("^" + $("#staton").val())) {
                validSelect = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        // if value entered was not found in array - clear input
        if (!validSelect) $("#staton").val("");
    },
    select: function(e){
        isSelected = true;
    },
    close: function(e){
        // if selection is invalid or not selected from the list - clear input
        if (!validSelect || !isSelected) $("#staton").val("");
    },
    dataSource: datasource
});
```

As you can see, this approach requires the array from the server side on load so that it can match during the filtering event of the widget.

Answer (score 0):

I found this on Telerik's site by just using the change event.  For me this works best.  I added the "value === ''" check.  This will catch when the user "clears" the selection.

[Here's the link to the full article.](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/editors/autocomplete/how-to/input/restrict-user-input)

```
      $("#countries").kendoAutoComplete({
        dataSource: data,
        filter: "startswith",
        placeholder: "Select country...",
        change: function() {
          var value = this.value();
          if (value === '') return;
          var found = false;
          var data = this.dataSource.view();

          for(var idx = 0, length = data.length; idx < length; idx++) {
            if (data[idx] === value) {
              found = true;
              break;
            }
          }

          if (!found) {
            this.value("");
            alert("Custom values are not allowed");
          }
        }
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

In my AutoComplete Change event I check for a selected item and clear the cell if not selected.

```js
    function myAutoComplete_OnChange(e)
    {
        if (this.dataItem())
        {
            // Don't use filtered value as display, instead use this value.
            e.sender.element[0].value = this.dataItem().WidgetNumber;
        }
        else
        {
            var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
            grid.dataItems()[grid.select().index()].WidgetKey = null;
            grid.dataItems()[grid.select().index()].WidgetNumber = null;
        }
    }
```